# Specman / E "UML like" took tool to generate a Class diagram. Do you know?

Tags: verilog, specman

I am looking for a tool that can generate Class diagram (UML style) of specman / E programming language.

I search in the web and couldn't find any.

Does anyhow have some insight on this matter?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, "eDoc" is *the* Specman documentation extraction tool.  If it doesn't have UML class diagrams, then no one does.  eDoc is using the javadoc tool to automatically document the code, so if someone can generate UML class diagrams from javadoc input, then perhaps you can intercept the javadoc source and manipulate it to generate UML class diagrams.  [Ask Cadence.](http://support.cadence.com)

If you want to run eDoc for your entire testbench, then run the following lin on the Specman CLI *after* loading your entire testbench:

```
write doc -detail -no_source_links -overwrite -dir=./testbench_edoc @*
```

There is a "tree" view of the class hierarchy which is reachable from the main page generated by the above command.  It shows you the class inheritance tree, but it doesn't give you a UML class diagram.

The documentation for eDocs is in [section "Generating and Using eDoc Reports" of sn_usage.pdf](http://support.cadence.com/wps/PA_DocumentViewer/pubs//sn_usage/sn_usage8.2/sn_usage.pdf#page=492).  I believe the javadoc version of eDocs was introduced in Specman 8.2